# Assembly Hex Dump

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am attempting to learn debugging in x86 assembly and am trying to debug my simple C program. However, I am confused as to how large values (like strings) are stored in memory. For example, lets say I store the string VEQ9SZ9T8I62ZCIWE6RKZDE6AZSI2 at address 0012E965 in register EBX and I look at the hex dump at that address, how do I know where it ends? Say I didn't have a nice ASCII string stored at that location, how would I know where the hex dump ended for that particular address? As you can see, I am quite a beginner at assembly so I thank everyone for his/her patience and help.

Comment: I mean the beginning of a value starts at address X, but hwo do I know where it ends in the hex dump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mostly a matter of interpretation. How a string (or any data in memory) is interpreted is (not surprisingly) defined by some code which interprets it. From just looking at a hex dump of data you cannot say which method was used to create the string, but chances are, that a common method was used. Null-terminated strings are easily recognized by a tailing zero, some strings may be prepended by it's length in bytes or chars. It's also possible that the size is not encoded in data memory but was put in as an immediate value inside the program.

Comment: So there is no way for me to identify where a value, say a string or number, ends in the hex dump?

Comment: Correct, there is no _definite_ way without looking at the code which interprets it. On many occasions you can make quite a good guess though, strings beeing the most simple ones.

Answer (score 2):

Depends who stored or generated the string. If it is generated by the assembler or a C program/library, it is most likely a C string.

For storing strings there are at some possibilities:

- Using a terminating 0 character, aka C string. To determine the length of the string you have to call a function like `strlen`. In this case the string ends where the first 0 char is.
- Storing the length of the string in a separate variable at the beginning. The length variable can be of byte, 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit width.
- Storing the length of the string and a pointer to an address in a global memory pool.

Additionally there are variants for storing wide chars, UTF-8 and such, and a mixture between everything. As assembler programmer its up to you what you use internally. It does make sense to use an format which can be used by the OS (like in file names) or which is common to programs or libraries you want to use. So C strings are probably most common in assembly programs.

Comment: So I can find the end of any stored value, be it a string or whatever, at a particular address by looking in the hex dump for 00?